# Laptop display/screen covered with lines

Tags: display, dell-inspiron

I am facing issue with screen/display of  my dell inspiron n4050 as shown in linked image  from last few days despite multiple restarts

[image: enter link description here]]

Comment: it looks like the cable connecting the display is loose.

Comment: Looks like a busted screen or cable connection to motherboard.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Try using an external monitor temporarily to test. If it works, the issue is with the cable or display.